# Segregating contextmenu and mousedown listeners

Tags: javascript, events, event-listener

I'm trying to use several mouse event listeners. These include mousedown and contextmenu. The issue I have is that when I want the contextmenu listener to run, the mousedown event also runs.

I think you can get the event to determine which event happened, just not sure of the syntax. This is what I plan to do:

```js
$("#temp_canv").mousedown(e => {this.line_down(e);});

$("#temp_canv").contextmenu(e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //...*context menu code*
});

line_down(e)
{
    if(e.*whatever will give me the events associated does not have contextmenu as well.* != contextmenu) //<--not sure of the syntax
    {
        //*Run only line_down events that are not associated with context menu*
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Turns out you just need to do "if(e.button == 0)" for a right click. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

I will add: I have three handlers in my function at once for mousedown, mouseup and contextmenu.    For contextmenu, I set the condition if(eventRightBtn.button == 2), for mousedown and mouseup if(event.button == 0) .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).